# Actionscript xmlsocket doesn't read data which is write by the nodejs net module server. but server read the data correctly. any solution?

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, websocket, xmlsocket

**Node js net module server code:**

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (connection) {
    console.log('client connected');

connection.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data from flash = ' + data);

    var jsonData = {};
    jsonData.message = "joined";

    var d = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

    connection.write(d);

});

connection.on('end', function () {
    console.log('client disconnected');
});

// connection.pipe(connection);
});
server.listen(3055, function () {
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

**Action script code**

```
this.login_socket.connect(this.server_ip,3055);
         this.login_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT,this.login_socket_onConnection);
         this.login_socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA,this.login_onData);
         this.login_socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,this.login_socket_onIOErrorEvent);
         this.login_socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,this.login_socket_SecurityErrorEvent);
         this.login_socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,this.login_socket_closeErrorEvent);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use xml socket with node js net module? I have tried everything but this doesn't work at all. I want to create a socket connection for a flash game to the server. I am using laravel as backend. If anyone knows how to create it with php tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Any error on client side? I think there should be a **SecurityErrorEvent** because AS3 socket will not work without correct crossdomain policy, while I don't see one in your node.js code.

Comment: Client accept data when i send client data back as it is. But any other doesn't accepted. Can you tell how to crossdomain policy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You say that if you send "AAA" from client to server and then echo it back, it's fine. But if you send "BBB" instead - it's not fine?

Comment: yes. but "BBB" not client to server. From server to client only.

Comment: If sending works **at all** then it works. That looks like you're missing something. Like 0-byte string terminator at the end of the packet. You need to examine what you are sending to and from server, byte-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (connection) {

    console.log('client connected');

    connection.setEncoding("utf8");

    // on receive data from client
    connection.on('data', function (data) {

        console.log('data from flash = ' + data);

        var d = JSON.stringify({
            message: "joined"
        }) + "\0";

        connection.write(d);
    });

    // on connection end
    connection.on('end', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });

    // on error
    connection.on("error", function (exception) {
        console.log('an error occurred: ' + exception);
    });
});

server.listen(3055, function () {
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

I change nodejs server code to above code and it works fine now.